# Android "observer"

Tags: android, button, background, task, observer-pattern

I have a small app which runs in background doing some tasks which basically detects the user behavior inside the Android Music application.

I want to check in background if the user pressed the back, play/stop or skip button. It seems like I can access information about the current playing song but I have no idea how to put an "observer" to watch those buttons.

Does anyone have an idea to help with?

Comment: This isn't possible and would be a huge security hole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem!

I checked the Android Music App source code and there's a class on com.android.music.MediaPlaybackService wich gives control and you can even switch between activities.

I created a BroadcastReceiver inside a background thread to watch anything from MediaPlaybackService.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite certain why Falmarri chose to use a comment rather than an answer, since his comment is correct: "This isn't possible and would be a huge security hole".

It also assumes the existence of "the Android Music application". There is no single "the Android Music application". There are hundreds, perhaps thousands of "Android Music" apps on the Market. Android devices come with a wide range of pre-installed "Android Music application", based upon whatever the device manufacturer chooses.

You are welcome to:

- write your own "the Android Music application", or
- find an open source "the Android Music application" and contribute to it

---

**UPDATE:** To clarify a bit, the "this isn't possible and would be a huge security hole" is for "how to put an 'observer' to watch those buttons". If that were possible, apps could steal passwords and PINs from users.

There is no documented and supported API for the AOSP music player app, and I am unaware of any similar API for any other music player (though some probably have something).

Comment: How about the Last.FM app for android? It not detects only the music I'm listening at the moment but also when I change songs.

Comment: @Thiago Moreira Rocha: Whatever they are doing, not only is it not using an "'observer' to watch those buttons", but it is neither documented nor supported. See the update to the answer above.